# Problem with converting accented characters to uppercase

Tags: accents, uppercase

The command `\uppercase` does not work properly with certain accented characters, like  the Hungarian `ő` or `ű` or such characters as `ł`, `đ` and `ć`. If I type the characters like `\H{o}`, it works, but I'd like to type it directly as `ő`, as it's used multiple times.
Could you suggest a workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\uppercase{árvízt\H{u}űr\H{o}ő tükörfúrógép đdłlćc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `t1enc` is obsolete and should be replaced by `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\uppercase` is a TeX "primitive". If you use the LaTeX macro `\MakeUppercase` instead, you'll achieve your objective easily.

You should also replace the obsolete `\usepackage{t1enc}` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

[image]

Observe, incidentally, that the output of `\uppercase{ű}` is `ő`, which is rather incorrect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\string\uppercase}:
\uppercase{árvízt\H{u}űr\H{o}ő tükörfúrógép đdłlćc}

\medskip
\texttt{\string\MakeUppercase}:
\MakeUppercase{árvízt\H{u}űr\H{o}ő tükörfúrógép đdłlćc}
\end{document}
```